# JQuery Accordion with buttons - How to prevent opening?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I've been playing around with the Accordion in the JQuery UI library. I've created some headers and I added some buttons to them. Now I would like to be able to click the buttons without opening that section.

[image: Accordion]

My buttons are in fact ASP.Net buttons that generate scripts with `onclick="some scripting"`. This scripts still needs to be executed. Any ideas?

Comment: I think its because your click event is bubbling up through the dom which is then opening the section. Try onclick="some scripting; return false;"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they're nested you could catch this click event before it's bubbling up to parent elements by using

```
$('#buttonid').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    //Your Code here(For example a call to your function)
});
```

You shouldn't use onClick in the markup, if you're working with a JS Framework anyways

Comment: Yeah, I don't like the onclick either... but .Net gives it to me.

Comment: Depending on how you implemented them, you could call the ASP methods from `$.ajax()` jQuery-Functions, too. Maybe this here: **http://www.seoasp.net/post/2008/07/16/jQuery-To-Call-ASPNET-Page-Methods-and-Web-Services.aspx** would interest you